# How to manage common dependencies between project and frameworks in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a framework (lets say XYZ) which uses a third party framework e.g Alamofire. The project in which i am importing my XYZ framework also uses the same third party framework. How can i manage this common dependency in my project to avoid duplication.

The XYZ framework has resources like storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way...

1. In target settings of main application add & embed both frameworks

[image: demo1]

2. In target settings of XYZ framework add non-embedding dependency

[image: demo2]

3. all linking will be done by Xcode and every framework will be included in main application bundle only once, so use `import Alamofire` in both target sources as usual

[image: demo]

Demo prepared & tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

Comment: getting following error when running main application.                                                    
  dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
 
  Reason: image not found

Comment: Check application bundle where Alamofire.framework is located, it might be copied in some other subfolders, so it will be needed to correct location. It should be copied into Frameworks as shown above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. A minor thing that I wasn't aware of. This doesn't cause any issue on debug builds, however when we upload to AppStore this has to be addressed.